# showing UTF-16 emojis received from JSON in text view - Android

Tags: android, json

I got the emoji as UTF 16 in JSON and the json look like this

```
{
   "name":"Crying Face"
  ,"code":"\\ud83d\\ude22"
}
```

I tried to write the code in textview but it is printed as text

I tried also to convert the \u to 0x

```
0xd83d0xde22
```

It prints it out as plain text

how can we show it as Emoji?

**UPDATE:**

after i saved the object to database the `\\` was removed and it looks like this in the database:

[image: from database]

Answer (score 0):

Why is it `\\u`?   It should be \u.  \u escapes the \, making it a literal \ so the emoji isn't recognized as a character escape code.

Comment: how can we remove the escape character ?

Comment: Assuming you have the file locally, delete the first \ of each pair.  If its generated by the server, fix the server.

Comment: i dont have the file, it is sent from server side like that. i have no permission to edit it

Comment: THen talk to the guy who does.  He has a bug.  The alternative is to write a parser for it and parse the string for \\uXXXX and turn that into the character code for XXXX, but you shouldn't need to do that-  he should fix his stuff.  IF you're working at someplace that won't fix their stuff, find a better job, it isn't worth the hastle.

Comment: Please check the update. the problem is surely not in the \\u and it is somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `EmojiconTextView` of this custom library: https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

```
android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
```

In this way, you can set any emoji like you do for any string.